# Given binary matrix, a centre point and an angle, find the first 1 element it will meet in both direction

Tags: geometry

background:
I am using a n x m matrix to represent a map. The boundary / obstacle will be represented by 1 and open space will represent by 0.
Given an orientation(angle) and the position of the robot (represented by a single element in a matrix), I want to know the closest boundary on the left and right of the robot, how should I do it?

Comment: Do you mean "find the nearest boundary or obstacle" or just the nearest boundary? Do you want only integer coordinates, or the points where the left-right line leave the rectangle, even if they are not integer? Is the robot able to face in any direction at all, or only in certain directions (such as towards one of the adjacent points, or maybe even just at other points on the map).

Comment: The robot is able to face any angle, I just want to know the coordinate of immediate 1 element to the left and right of the robot.

Comment: The line could hit the 1 element not directly but will also count as a hit

Comment: Why would a line which does not hit the 1 element count as a hit? Please be more specific. Do you mean to say that the elements are meant as square cells, and the line doesn't have to pass through the center of the square, but could hit any point of the square? Is hitting a single corner enough? The obvious solution would be “iterate over all obstacle bits, compare each against the input”. Could this approach work for you? Have you any more specific problem formulating the details of this approach?

Comment: "the elements are meant as square cells, and the line doesn't have to pass through the center of the square, but could hit any point of the square" << exactly.

Comment: I  imagine the angle could be converted to a slope and form a parametric formula of the line, then I can use this to go through both direction of the line, until I hit a 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the angle $\theta$ is with respect to the positive $x$-direction, with the positive $y$-direction being at $\theta = {\pi\over 2}$, and if the point where the robot is currently at is $(x_0, y_0)$ then the equation you want is $$y = y_0 + {x - x_0\over \tan \theta}.$$

Keep incrementing or decrementing $x$ by 1, calculate the corresponding $y$, then round it to the nearest integer. Continue until you find an obstacle.

Note that when $\theta = \pm {\pi\over2}$, this becomes just $y = y_0$ (a horizontal line), and when $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$, this becomes $x = x_0$ (a vertical line).